# latitude and longitude returned with pipe symbol.How to handle this?

Tags: java, gps, latitude-longitude

I am using QAS service for address picking in a java application.If I select a particular address the service returns various data related to that address.In that data the latitude and longitude (for a particular address) are being returned as `34.102709|34.101509` and `118.324710|118.326160` respectively.

**My question is,is this a valid format for lat and long?and if so than what does it represent? and how can I pre process it so that I save only a single big decimal value in database for latitude and longitude?.**

Thanks.

Comment: What if it was `34.102709XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX34.101509`? What does it matter if you know you can parse it and get the latitude and longitude?

Comment: Looks like it's expressed in degrees. 60 minutes = 1 degree and 60 seconds = 1 minute. So 34.102709 = 34 degrees, 6' and 9.7524"

Comment: Problem with parsing.I do not know what does the pipe symbol represents.does it represent a valid value like latitude is 34.102709 to 34.101509.I am asking if its one of the standard ways of showing latitude or longitude.?

Comment: It looks like a separator.

Comment: Hi Cheeta, I've just deleted my answer below as I had made a few assumptions. If you can let us know which country you are searching against and, if you have it, an example search that returns this information I'll be able to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You are not likely to see these too often, but the pipe is used as a separator when there are multiple possible enhancements for a single address. You can look in the documentation for "multiple dataplus separators" to see how you can configure these.

With this result, you have two lats and two longs for the same address: two pairs of coordinates:

- 34.102709, 118.324710
- 34.101509, 118.326160

*How can one address have two co-ordinates?*

I can answer this better if you can let us know the country you are searching against but it is either the way the data is supplied or a result of us combining data from different suppliers.

- Some suppliers provide us data in this way - multiple coordinates (or other enhancement information) for one address - especially when dealing with non-postal addresses. For example there may be two fixed cranes close to each other and their 'addresses' are identical. They are however in slightly different positions so we return multiple possible coordinates.
- When combining data from different suppliers, they are sometimes defined to different levels of granularity. For example, the reference data (country) you are searching against may be to household level (letter box) but the data we get with co-ordinates may be to a more detailed level so may contain information to sub-premise level. If this is the case, we return multiple dataplus to one address.

*What should you do when getting multiple dataplus for one address?*

Depends upon your need! If you can give a bit more information about how you are using it or [contact our support teams to talk it over](http://www.qas.co.uk/about-us/locations.htm) then we can clarify. You may be able to just take the first value, you may need to create two entries, you might have to average the values out. You're going to have to choose the best approach depending upon your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a valid format for lat and long, and if so than what does it represent?

Here's the format in question: `34.102709|34.101509 118.324710|118.326160`  It's a location just east of Luoma Lake in China.  Unless the longitude has an implied minus sign.  Then it's a location in Hollywood, California, USA.

The first pair of values represent a latitude range.  The second pair of values represent a longitude range.

> How can I pre process it so that I save only a single big decimal value in database for latitude and longitude?.

If you want one latitude and longitude, you can average the range of the latitude and average the range of the longitude.  In other words, add the two latitude numbers together and divide by 2.  Then add the two longitude numbers together and divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that values `34.102709|34.101509` and `118.324710|118.326160` represents some area:

```
latitudeMin = 34.101509
latitudeMax = 34.102709

longitudeMin = 118.324710
longitudeMax = 118.326160
```